# Should $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] be a valid document root that all sites hosted can use?

Tags: php, apache

Should $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] be setup properly so that developers can reference the value in their PHP scripts?

We had setup the document root so that it loads a specific site off the root and everything else was aliased accordingly.

However, a developer has used $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in all his require statements and this configuration breaks his site. He also has several thousands files to go through and fix in its current state.

I think it should be setup properly (ie. point to the appropriate physical path) and we should load the default site using an alternative method. However, as a new web server administrator, I'm not sure if there are industry standards in regards to this.

Comment: Personally I think it should just be documented. If you are sharing doc root, let the developers know what protocol to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you shouldn't use `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`.

I do know there is no reason to use it because you can use `__DIR__` (or `dirname(__FILE__)` on older versions of PHP).

---

[Autoloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) is by far the preferred way to deal with includes.

Comment: Agreed. However, I have some legacy stuff to deal with that doesn't use Autoloading.

Comment: Sure, code that works with includes doesn't always work with autoloading. Usually this means there are some bad practices in the code such as duplicate class names or files that do more than just define a class.

Comment: I was looking at the code this morning and I just noticed that 1) no classes are being used, all straight up PHP and 2) includes are done using require_once... :)